# 301 redirect for IIS 7.5 to replace domain only and maintain page structure

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have searched far and wide and have been unable to find a conclusive answer for my issue...

My old domain = www.olddomain.com
My new domain = www.newdomain.com

This is the only thing that changes, I have lots of other pages in the website and a number of links across the internet that I want to 301 redirect and not be punished by the search engines for SEO.

I have a Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 so can't use an .htaccess file (which I have used many times before successfully) and need to transfer:

www.olddomain.com/folder/page.html
to
www.newdomain.com/folder/page.html

Please can someone help me with the correct URL rewrite pattern for my web.config for my entire website, not just individual pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use URL Rewrite from: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Even in the UI it includes a default template for "Canonical domains" that will do exactly that:

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.newdomain\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your reply, its not a Canonical Domain issue that I have, its 2 separate domains. for example www.foo.com to www.bar.com

Do you have a solution for different domains?
Thanks

Comment: unless I'm missing something that is the same problem, basically this rule will redirect to www.newdomain.com anything that is not being sent to it while respecting the URL (aka just concatenating the URL and Query string). Which unless I'm mistaken that is what you are saying. Note that if you want to specifically match www.olddomain.com change the condition to: pattern="^www\.olddomain\.com$"  />

Comment: It shouldn't, did you copy the parenthesis above in the match? {R:1} will make sure that it adds all the data captured by the regex in the match, meaning the entire URL, so it should preserve that.

Comment: This is my rule........

<rule name="Forward Old to New" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.olddomain\.co.uk$" negate="true"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.newdomain.co.uk/{R:1}" />
   </rule>

Comment: Your rule is saying "If it is NOT olddomain.co.uk then redirect to newdomin.co.uk". Is that what you tried to do? It thought you wanted. You also removed the http and the slash from my rule breaking it. This is what I think you want (same above): <rule name="Forward Old to New" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^newdomain\.co\.uk$" negate="true"/>
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://newdomain.co.uk/{R:1}" />
</rule>

Comment: I think the comments strips out the http and the slash. I created your rule exactly as above - replacing the domains and adding the appropriate http and slash and it still redirects to the root of the new domain. Does it matter that both sites are on the same web server, albeit in different application pools and sites?